# stack in listview flutter infinite height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to put a card between an image and the rest of the page

so i used **stack** in **listview builder** but it doesn't give the expected result

what i want

[image]

what i get => https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxy41.jpg

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            first(_listviewurl, _listViewData[0], _listviewwe9t),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
              child: Text(
                "News",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 32),
              ),
            ),
        Positioned(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 5,
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 9,
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.9,
        child: Card(
          semanticContainer: true,
          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          child: Image.asset(
            "images/img1.jpg",
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ),
      ),
          ],
        );
      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your card is in your listview and your listview's height is the same with your first Widget, you can add Container as parent widget of your Stack widget and set height for it:

```
Container(
  child: Stack(...)
)
```

Comment: well thank you man .. the first time i post a question and get an answer